# ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption does not work anymore

Tags: ios, fastlane

### Problem

We are using *Fastlane* to distribute our builds. In order to avoid the manual agreement to the export compliance, we have set the following key in our *info.plist*:

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
<false/>
```

Out of the blue, this stopped working. Also, the encryption pop-up has changed. Is there a new key that has to be added or has something else changed? Couldn't find any information.

Comment: Which Version of Fastlane? Have you tried to downgrade Fastlane Version? Which Version of Xcode? Native or React Native?

Comment: XCode 13 and I am using React Native 0.69.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Ok, it is unbelievably stupid. I edited the entry in my *info.plist*, but I had to edit it directly via XCode in the *Generals* tab. Seems like the version in XCode is the one which is really used and at some point in the build process being generated from the original *info.plist*.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, i got confused by Xcode that renames the keys when displayed in Xcode compared to when you look for this key in the raw info.plist:
[image]